# Disable and enable Cloud Run service using Terraform is removing all deployed services

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run

Today, when I tried to disable and re-enable CloudRun service using Terraform, I observed that all the currently deployed CloudRun services are deleted. These are not disabled, actually deleted completely.

```
resource "google_project_service" "cloudrun" {
  project = var.project_id
  service = "run.googleapis.com"
}
```

This is a different behavior compared to any other google's serverless offerings. I disabled and re-enabled GCE API service and that kept all the existing GCE instances. Same is the case with Pub/Sub, CloudSQL etc.

Did anybody observe this behavior? Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's likely due to this caveat about Cloud Run:

> Cloud Run does not offer a direct way to make a service stop serving traffic

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/services#disable)

Luckily if you are defining all of your Cloud-Run services via Terraform you should be able to re-deploy everything but agreed that it's inconsistent.

Comment: And I was able to reproduce this behavior in a brand new GCP project. Here are the steps I followed:
1) Enable "CloudRun" API using Terraform 
2) Manually create a new CloudRun service using console
3) Disable/Destroy the "CloudRun" API using Terraform
4) The manually created "CloudRun" service is now gone. Deleted.

Comment: @SarmaPasumarthi, yeah this makes sense based on the documentation. There is no disabling of services, they exist or don't or exist but have permission revoked. Disabling of the API removes the services which makes sense since it's a completely managed service with no disable options. If this answer makes sense to you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer#:~:text=It%20simply%20means%20that%20the,answer%20corresponds%20to%20reputation%20gains.)

Comment: Jake: Thank you for that insight.. What other GCP services I need to be careful about?